How to make a gt table responsive in a quarto website
I would like to hide a couple of columns of a {gt} interactive table in a quarto website, given the condition that the screen is smaller than certain amount of pixels.
In this example I want to hide every column between disp and qsec when the screen is smaller than 450 px.
library(gt)

mtcars |>
  gt() |>
  tab_options(table.width = px(850)) |>
  opt_interactive(use_search = TRUE, use_pagination = TRUE)

